# How to declare a path without the drive letter?

Tags: vb.net, path

Example i have picture folder located at

```
Dim path As String = "D:\Student Picture\Student-" + textbox_Search.Text + ".jpg"
```

Something like that. now i want the the picture folder to just paste it in debug folder can i call it without the drive letter something like this ??

```
Dim path As String = "\bin\debug\Student Picture\Student-" + textbox_Search.Text + ".jpg"
```

Its not working. The reason why i want to achieve this is example i use my program in another computer but the other computer don't have drive D: then my program will not work because in my code all of the student picture declared in drive D: thank you so much.

Comment: Try use `"Student Picture\Student-"` directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the application startup path and create the folder in either the Debug or Release locations, depending which you're running. The folder would be created within the directory in which the end-user runs the compiled application.

```
Dim PicPath As String = Application.StartupPath & "\Student Picture
If Not My.Computer.FileSystem.DirectoryExists(PicPath) Then
    My.Computer.FileSystem.CreateDirectory(PicPath)
End If
PicPath &= "\Student-" & textbox_Search.Text & ".jpg""
```

Small edit- I realised you wanted to include file name as well. Please do not use "+" when concatenating strings, the proper operator is "&" use the "+" operator only when youre doing math and some other unique cases, such as datatable expression column concatenation.

Comment: Thank you so much.  Trying to search this question for almost a month.